# Youtube API v3: Searching for a video and uploading it to a playlist

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am trying to put together three individual codes I found as examples in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs:

- Create a playlist in my channel (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert)
- Search for video(s) with a given keyword in their title (among the videos I have in the channel) (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)
- Add the videos to the playlist (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert)

I am able to sucessfully run the codes separately, but fail to combine them. Specifically: after the playlist is created, the code needs to get the playlist ID. Likewise, when a video is found that meets the search criteria, the video ID is needed for it to be added to the playlist. 
I have used Python. Please, could anyone help?

This is the code I have:

```
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secrets.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        forMine=True,
        maxResults=50,
        order="date",
        q="searchcriteria",
        type="video"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)
    vid=response['videoId']

    request2 = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
          "snippet": {
            "playlistId": "myplaylistIdcomeshere",
            "resourceId": {
              "videoId": "vid",
              "kind": "youtube#video",
              "playlistId": "myplaylistIdcomeshereagain"
            },
            "position": 0
          }
        }
    )

    respons2 = request2.execute()

    print(response2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From the response from the search part I have the following (edited to remove unnnecesary details):

{'kind': 'youtube#searchListResponse', 'etag': '"longetag"', 'nextPageToken': 'anotherlongtext=', 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 1, 'resultsPerPage': 50}, 'items': [{'kind': 'youtube#searchResult', 'etag': '"theetagofthevideodfound"', 'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'THISISWHATIWANT'}, 'snippet': {'publishedAt': '2020-02-22T19:33:03.000Z', 'channelId': 'MyChannelTitle', 'title': 'TitleOfTheVideo', 'description': '', 'thumbnails': {VideoThumbnails}}, 'channelTitle': 'MyChannelTitle', 'liveBroadcastContent': 'none'}}]}

I have tried with 
vid=response['videoId']
vid=response['id']

But none of them worked

Comment: Can you also include the code snippet you used

Comment: Thank you, I have added the code and the options I have tried. I read the documentation, but I do not know how to retrieve the 'id' from the response

Answer (score 0):

The response of inserting an item to the playlist should return a [playlist resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert#response_1) which contains the playlist ID

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#resource

Similarly, when you search for a video you get a [`search_resource` in response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response_1) which contains a list of videos with IDs

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a way that works. Placing this piece of code in between requests does it. Posting in here in case someone else runs into the same question:

```
for search_result in response.get('items', []):
      videos.append('%s (%s)' % (search_result['snippet']['title'],
                                 search_result['id']['videoId']))
      vid=search_result['id']['videoId']
```